# Calculate Exact Age From Mysql Database Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem while printing exact age using php. The years of the age are printing exactly but when it comes to months and days they often goes to negative values.

Here is the snippet of the code and full code is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/2gapa8o4n8s72qs/print22result.php).

```
$ag = date('Y') - substr($row11['dob'],6);
        $mn = date('m') - substr($row11['dob'],3,2);
        $dy = date('d') - substr($row11['dob'],0,2);
```

Comment: can you post your output and expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your age calculation method is not Right, bcz by separation from today's year to birth year is fine but when it come to month and date it will gives negative value, direct separation will not work for age calculation. 
Use following code.

```
    function ageCalculator($dob){
    if(!empty($dob)){
        $birthdate = new DateTime($dob);
        $today   = new DateTime('today');
        $ag = $birthdate->diff($today)->y;
        $mn = $birthdate->diff($today)->m;
        $dy = $birthdate->diff($today)->d;
        return "$ag Years $mn Months $dy Days";
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

$row11 = array('dob'=>'02-01-1995');
echo ageCalculator($row11['dob']);

//OUTPUT

22 Years 9 Months 20 Days
```

Here you can find the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8eh4-Yt9AgvYThYYmlvLWlLV1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually we hired a developer for our school software and now he is not responding and i need the age displaying correct data by tomorrow. can you exactly tell me where should i assign the

    $row11['dob']

it will be very nice of you if i get the exact answer.

Comment: As you requested I edited in your file, just replace [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8eh4-Yt9AgvYThYYmlvLWlLV1k/view?usp=sharing) file to yours and don't forget mark it as answer

Comment: i am receiving this error while running the file provided by you


Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()


the php version is 5.2.6. Kindly fix the issue.

Comment: Oops!!!! U should change to php newer version near to 5.6 r 7. No time to fix now.

Comment: Ok but does it effect the files present currently on wamp?